# React native typescript useEffect not updating array

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, expo, pusher

Am trying to create a real time voting using Pusher, typescript and react native, but the candidates array is not being updated and displayed on the useEffect function. but when I run the same code lines from a normal vote it works (the candidates array is updated and displayed correctly);

```
const [candidates, setCandidates] = useState([]);

const vote = (id, position, name, name2) => {
  var newVoteData = ({ voterName: votingData.voterName, voterId: votingData.voterId, position: position, candidateId: id, candidateName: name });
  setProcessingModal(true);
  fetch("http://172.20.10.4:8000/mobile/vote", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(newVoteData),
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      if (data.status == "ok") {
       // This block of code works, updates the particular        
       // candidate voteCount and setCandidates correctly
        setProcessingModal(false);
        alert("Yay!!! , you have successfully voted");
        const updatedData = candidates.map(x => (x.id === id ? { ...x, voteCount: data.voteCount } : x)); //updates votecount on candidate

        let newArr = updatedData.sort((x, y) => {
          return y.voteCount - x.voteCount;
        });
        setCandidates(updatedData);
      } else {
        setProcessingModal(false);
        alert(data);
      }

    })
    .catch((error) => {
      setProcessingModal(false);
      alert(error);
      console.error("Error:", error);
    });
};
```

the below useEffect function is where am having issues, the array for some reason is not being updated

```
useEffect(() => {

  const liveUpdateCandidates = (id, voteCount) => {

    alert(voteCount);
    const updatedData = candidates.map(x => (x.id === id ? { ...x, voteCount: voteCount } : x));//updates votecount on candidate does not work here
    console.log("afer");
    let newArr = updatedData.sort((x, y) => {
      return y.voteCount - x.voteCount;
    });
    setCandidates(newArr);
  };

  //Pusher.logToConsole = true;
  const pusher = new Pusher("3580cab8bee36d295917", {
    cluster: "eu",
    encrypted: true,
  });

  const channel = pusher.subscribe("votebooth-channel");
  channel.bind("App\\Events\\BoothEvent", function(data) {
    liveUpdateCandidates(data.candidateId, data.voteCount);
  });


  return (() => {
    pusher.unsubscribe("votebooth-channel");
    // pusher.unsubscribe('channel_name2');
  });
}, [candidates]);
```

Below is a sample of the returned array

```
[
  { "id": "3", "name": "Kwaku", "candidateUserId": null, "gender": "Male", "philosophy": "Good", "voteCount": "132" },
  { "id": "22", "name": "rose", "candidateUserId": null, "gender": "Female", "philosophy": "Php", "voteCount": "1" },
];
```

Comment: check first whether the candidates is having some changes because until the value is not changed useEffect will not work.

Comment: and donot use function inside useEffect , just call inside it based on conditions like if(candidates){  liveUpdateCandidates();} and make sure the data you are passing to function is correct

Comment: Okay let me try it

Comment: I tried it as you said, using the function outside useEffect and not work

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things here I would fix.

First of all you are using a useEffect which has `candidates` as a dependency and using `setCandidates` inside of that useEffect. Dependencies in a useEffect mean it will trigger everytime the dependency value changes.

**This means that the useEffect will enter into a loop and it will most likely crash and nothing will work.**

Secondary, you are defining a value for `newArr` which is never being used, you should remove that.

Finally, your code needs some refactoring. Try using one useEffect for the listener and another for the updating of data. Also, if it has several lines I would extract it to a function with a clear name of what it's doing.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, I used the liveUpdateCandidates->setCandidates inside useEffect cause I saw example online when I was scouring the web for solution hence the reason why you see the code is not refactored yet, please can you help me with last part of your answer, code to use one useEffect as listener and another for updating data.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the id variable is sent to liveUpdateCandidates function for some reason is been sent as string so I had to convert it to int first. like below

```
const liveUpdateCandidates = (id, voteCount) => { 
  alert(id);
        var candId = parseInt(id);// the solution is to convert the id to int first
                const updatedData = candidates.map(x => (x.id === candId ? { ...x, voteCount: voteCount } : x));//updates votecount on candidate
                let newArr = updatedData.sort((x,y) => {return y.voteCount - x.voteCount});
                setCandidates(newArr);   
        };
```